# Can I rearrange the messaging menu list?

Tags: indicator, messaging-menu

This is my current messaging menu layout in Ubuntu 12.10:

[image: My Messaging Menu Layout]

I was wondering is there a way to change the list? I would rather have Thunderbird moved to the bottom. I tried uninstalling Thunderbird, which removed it from the list, but when I reinstalled it Thunderbird went back into that position. It seems the layout is set as you set-up the applications the first time which made me think there is something somewhere which defines how they are ordered in the list.

Any help would be great!

Comment: What a beautiful chat icons! Is it really 12.10?

Comment: The chat icons are from the Faenza theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found an easy way.

Open Dconf Editor, go to **com > canonical > indicator > messages**. You can change the order of **applications** there or even remove something.

[image: Re-arrange messaging menu]

Then, you should restart unity to changes take effect. So simply logout and login again, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `unity --replace`. The result is this:

[image: Re-arrange messagin menu - result]

**Notice:** If you disable all the online accounts associated with Empathy, the settings will be reset to the previous state; so to keep current arrangement, always keep at least one account enabled.

Comment: Sorry for being late! I’ve found it just yesterday. :D

Comment: Better late than never ;-)