# dconf editor message entry missing

Tags: messaging-menu, dconf

I tried to rearrange my messaging menu in Ubuntu 12.04 following this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/269231/170356 .
But in my dconf-editor is no such entry "…messages".

The command `dconf list /com/canonical/indicator/` only returns: appmenu/ datetime/ power/ and sound/

Thanks for any idea how to get this entry back, or an other way to rearrange the messaging-menu!

Comment: I think you need to install and use either evolution or Thunderbird for the messaging option to be available. I have tried it with Evolution and it doesn't work.

Comment: no, the messaging menu is in the there panel, and it works (with thunderbird, empathy, skype etc).
I just want to change the order of the icons (see link above)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. If I find anything, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Messaging Menu API changed between 12.04 and 12.10. The GSettings key in the linked answer is for the 12.10 version, and does not exist in 12.04.

I do not believe there is a way to change the ordering in 12.04 (without modifying the code). From a quick glance at the old code, it looks like everything is sorted automatically.